# guildMemberAdd event handler issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This will be my third question of the day because I am obviously not smart with this. I am using discord.js v12 and my issue this time is with an event handler. The event handler has worked fine so far with things so far like the message or ready. I am right now trying to get a guildMemberAdd event that gives a new person that joins a role and then sends a message in the logs chat indicating they joined. When a user joins, the bot crashes. The guildMemberAdd works on my main index.js file, but won't work under the event handler.

crash log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1O7d.jpg

here are a few pieces of code if they are needed.

Event Handler:

```
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');

module.exports = (client) => {
    const load = dirs => {
        const events = readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js'));
        
        for(let file of events){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            let eventName = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
        }
    }
    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(x => load(x));
}
```

guildMemberAdd:

```
module.exports = (Discord, client, guildMember) => {
    console.log(guildMember);
    
    guildMember.roles.add(guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member"));
    guildMember.channels.cache.get('767090422626779149').send('test');
}
```

index.js

```
// heads up that I'm using discord.js v12.4.1 because v13.1.0 is weird and I don't understand it lol

const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Discord.Client(); // client = name of  bot

// client.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
   // guildMember.roles.add(guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member"));
// });

['aliases', 'commands'].forEach(x => client[x] = new Discord.Collection());
['command', 'event'].forEach(x => require(`./handlers/${x}`)(client));

client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN); // SECRET TOKEN
```

I haven't used discord.js or JavaScript in at least a year so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem passing the `guildMember` object.

Maybe changing this can help you:

```js
client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client)); //change this

client.on(eventName, (...args) => event.bind(null, client, ...args)) //to this
```

> Note: I am also not 100% sure if you can use `guildMember` or if you have to use `member`.

Comment: This answer didn't fully work, but it helped me find out that I forgot to include Discord in the event handler at module.exports